# LDAP empty labeledURI

Tags: php, ldap

Hey guys I am currently trying to get some data out of a ldap Active Directory and I used a php code I found on the Internet:

```
<?php

//LDAP Bind paramters, need to be a normal AD User account.
$ldap_password = 'AD_Password';
$ldap_username = 'AD_Username@domain.tld';
$ldap_connection = ldap_connect("domain.tld");

if (FALSE === $ldap_connection){
// Uh-oh, something is wrong...
echo 'Unable to connect to the ldap server';
}

// We have to set this option for the version of Active Directory we are using.
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or 
die('Unable to set LDAP protocol version');
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0); // We need this for doing an LDAP search.

if (TRUE === ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $ldap_username, $ldap_password)){

//Your domains DN to query
$ldap_base_dn = 'DC=domain,DC=tld,DC=tld';

//Get standard users and contacts
$search_filter = '(|(objectCategory=person)(objectCategory=contact))';

//Connect to LDAP
$result = ldap_search($ldap_connection, $ldap_base_dn, $search_filter);

if (FALSE !== $result){
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $result);

    // Uncomment the below if you want to write all entries to debug somethingthing 
    //var_dump($entries);

    //Create a table to display the output 
    echo '<h2>AD User Results</h2></br>';
    echo '<table border = "1"><tr bgcolor="#cccccc"><td>Username</td><td>Last Name</td><td>First Name</td><td>E-Mail Address</td><td>Home Phone</td></tr>';

    //For each account returned by the search
    for ($x=0; $x<$entries['count']; $x++){

        //
        //Retrieve values from Active Directory
        //

        //Windows Usernaame
        $LDAP_samaccountname = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]['samaccountname'][0])) {
            $LDAP_samaccountname = $entries[$x]['samaccountname'][0];
            if ($LDAP_samaccountname == "NULL"){
                $LDAP_samaccountname= "";
            }
        } else {
            //#There is no samaccountname s0 assume this is an AD contact record so generate a unique username

            $LDAP_uSNCreated = $entries[$x]['usncreated'][0];
            $LDAP_samaccountname= "CONTACT_" . $LDAP_uSNCreated;
        }

        //Last Name
        $LDAP_LastName = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]['sn'][0])) {
            $LDAP_LastName = $entries[$x]['sn'][0];
            if ($LDAP_LastName == "NULL"){
                $LDAP_LastName = "";
            }
        }

        //First Name
        $LDAP_FirstName = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]['givenname'][0])) {
            $LDAP_FirstName = $entries[$x]['givenname'][0];
            if ($LDAP_FirstName == "NULL"){
                $LDAP_FirstName = "";
            }
        }

        //Email address
        $LDAP_InternetAddress = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]['mail'][0])) {
            $LDAP_InternetAddress = $entries[$x]['mail'][0];    
            if ($LDAP_InternetAddress == "NULL"){
                $LDAP_InternetAddress = "";
            }
        }

        //Home phone
        $LDAP_HomePhone = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]['homephone'][0])) {
            $LDAP_HomePhone = $entries[$x]['homephone'][0];
            if ($LDAP_HomePhone == "NULL"){
                $LDAP_HomePhone = "";
            }
        }

        echo "<tr><td><strong>" . $LDAP_samaccountname ."</strong></td><td>" .$LDAP_LastName."</td><td>".$LDAP_FirstName."</td><td>".$LDAP_CompanyName."</td><td>".$LDAP_Department."</td><td>".$LDAP_OfficePhone."</td><td>".$LDAP_OfficeFax."</td><td>".$LDAP_CellPhone."</td><td>".$LDAP_DDI."</td><td>".$LDAP_InternetAddress."</td><td>".$LDAP_HomePhone."</td></tr>";


    } //END for loop
} //END FALSE !== $result

ldap_unbind($ldap_connection); // Clean up after ourselves.
echo("</table>"); //close the table

} //END ldap_bind

?>
```

I changed every variable I had to change and it works fine but now I tried to write a new part to get the path of the profile image.
My code looks like this:

```
            //Profile img
        $LDAP_ProfileImage = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]['labeledURI'][0])) {
            $LDAP_ProfileImage = $entries[$x]['labeledURI'][0]; 
            if ($LDAP_ProfileImage == "NULL"){
                $LDAP_ProfileImage = "";
            }
        }
```

This snippet is basically the same as the others that work and when I use SysInternals to check the contents of the AD there should be a string showing up, but the ldap search shows up as empty.

I also added the $LAP_ProfileImage to the "output" echo but it is still empty and I don't know what I am doing wrong. Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help,
Best regards Taccoman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ldap-extension is converting all attribute-names to lower case in the results array. So your value is most certainly available as

```
$entries[$x]['labeleduri'][0]
```

See also the section about Return Values at the [ldap_get_entries documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-get-entries.php).